# ConEmu - win key hotkeys intercepted by Windows -- Windows Bash

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, conemu

Win 10. None of the 'Win + ...' hotkeys are working for me in ConEmu. Windows intercepts them all. E.g.,

- Start ConEmu running Bash for Windows
- Make sure ConEmu has focus
- press Win + w
- Windows opens the "WINDOWS INK WORKSPACE"

Expected
 - ConEmu runs 'Create new console or new window...'

Here's a video of the problem: https://vimeo.com/290964378

Comment: What are you options on General page?

Comment: @Maximus thank you: that was it. I toggled on "Support special hotkeys...", and things are working now. I had looked at that setting about 20 times.... Why didn't I just try it...? Tooooo sleepy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Maximus' answer the comments to the original question -- please upvote his comment.

In Settings > General, I just needed to toggle on the "Support special hotkeys..." setting:

[image]

Comment: Not working for me... Think I´m gonna disable Windows Ink Workspace